# Constness of version method when it gets called by another method in the same class

Tags: c++, c++11, constants

I know that when there are both const and non-const versions of a method with the same name and parameters, the version chosen is determined by the const-ness of *this. (constness of the method is part of the signature right?)

But what happens when its being called by another method?

An example

```
class a{
   void b() const{
      c();
      //do fantastic things
   }
   const_iterator c() const;
   iterator c();
};
```

When I call b() from a nonconst instance of a, how I know which version of c() gets invoked?

Comment: "constness of the method is part of the signature right?" yes, as is lvalue/rvalue qualification

Comment: _When I call b() from a nonconst instance of a, how I know which version of c() gets invoked?_ ... a `const` method can only call other `const` methods, so `b() const` can only call `c() const`.

Answer (score 3):

From inside a function declared as const for a type, you can only call the const functions of that type.

Comment: What if the function were not const ? How would I know which one will be called ?

Comment: The non-const one, if there is one. Otherwise, the const one can be called.

Comment: Always in that order ? Is it specified by the standard ?

Comment: @Nin Yes, it is specified in the standard. I suggest you look it up.

Answer (score 3):

> But what happens when its being called by another method?

The same thing as when you call it from outside.

Keep in mind that member functions can be pictured *as if* they had an **invisible first parameter** `T* this`. In the case of `const` member functions, `T const* this`.

Now, this code:

```
class a{
   void b() const{
      c();
      //do fantastic things
   }
   const_iterator c() const;
   iterator c();
};
```

can be thought of as:

```
class a{
   void b(a const* this) const{ // pseudo code
      c(this); // pseudo code
      //do fantastic things
   }
   const_iterator c(a const* this) const; // pseudo code
   iterator c(a* this); // pseudo code
};
```

It follows that the `const` version of `c` is called, because you "pass it" a pointer to `a const`, not to `a`.